# How to create 2d arrray task problem with 0 output

Tags: c#, arrays

My task is to ask user for n number that determines the size of my array and the output. For example for n = 5, the output should look like this:

```
11111
12222
12333
12344
12345
```

This is my code Ive done so far. It prints the right amount of columns but it shows only 0, I can't figured out how to put there a numbers.My code:

```
int n;

Console.Write("Enter n amount of lines/columns: ");
n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

int[,] tab = new int[n, n];

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine();
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        Console.Write(tab[i, j]);
    }
 }

 Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Hi,  you never set any values when you make an array unless you set values at that time, its going to be at default which is 0..  so just like you set any variable you can set an array of say ints to be myarray[12,4]=23; that sets the row say 12 and column 4 (just remember to keep rows/cols in the same order, as 4,12 will be a different one.. so you would need to loop around your rows and columns entering data, very much like you did to print it, only asking for a number and setting it.

Comment: What is your current output?

Comment: @papanito From OP's question: _It prints the right amount of columns but it shows only 0_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to output to the console, then the following will output the lines you wanted:

```
int n;

Console.Write("Enter n amount of lines/columns: ");
n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < i + 1; j++)
        Console.Write(j + 1);

    for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
        Console.Write(i + 1);

    Console.WriteLine();
}
Console.ReadKey();
```

Outputs:

```
11111
12222
12333
12344
12345
```

If your goal is to actually propoulate a 2 dimensional array with those values, then this code will achieve the same with the result stored in the array:

```
int[,] tab = new int[n, n];

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    int k = 0;

    for (int j = 0; j < i + 1; j++)
        tab[i, k++] = j + 1;

    for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
        tab[i, k++] = i + 1;
}
```

The result:

```
?tab
{int[5, 5]}
    [0, 0]: 1
    [0, 1]: 1
    [0, 2]: 1
    [0, 3]: 1
    [0, 4]: 1
    [1, 0]: 1
    [1, 1]: 2
    [1, 2]: 2
    [1, 3]: 2
    [1, 4]: 2
    [2, 0]: 1
    [2, 1]: 2
    [2, 2]: 3
    [2, 3]: 3
    [2, 4]: 3
    [3, 0]: 1
    [3, 1]: 2
    [3, 2]: 3
    [3, 3]: 4
    [3, 4]: 4
    [4, 0]: 1
    [4, 1]: 2
    [4, 2]: 3
    [4, 3]: 4
    [4, 4]: 5
```

Comment: Thank you, my goal was with the 2 dimensional arrays. I knew that I need another integer that will be responsible of numbers but I didn't know where to put this or how. Now ill analyze your code to learn it. One more time thank you ! :)